# How to plot two files with error bars in gnuplot side by side?

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I have two files with three columns. The first column is the X, the second column is the Y - Mean, and the third is the error.

I need to plot these two files to compare the error between them. I can plot but the error bars overlap. I need them to stand side by side.

Archive 1

```
10 0.15127 0.0986
30 0.14606 0.10022
60 0.16739 0.10298
```

Archive 2

```
10  0.19177 0.10253
30  0.17864 0.12178
60  0.18111 0.11272
```

What I can plot

[image]

What I need
I need the two categories to be side by side with the bar showing the error for plus and minus and midpoint.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We will use the line number (column 0, shorthand $0) for the x coordinate and offset the second set of values by 1/10 unit on x

```
set offset 0.5, 0.5      # put whitespace on both sides of the data
set yrange [0:1]
plot 'ar1' using ($0):2:3:xtic(1) with yerrrorbars, \
     'ar2' using ($0+0.1):2:3 with yerrorbars
```

[image]